# alternative to c# foreach loop to get items from list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arraylist, foreach

I am hoping someone can lend a hand here to what must be a simple a problem. I have searched for an answer but I think part of the problem is I don't exactly know what I am asking. I have the following code.

```
@using System;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Linq;
@using System.Xml.Linq;

<div>
@{ 
  String URLString = "https://api3.libcal.com/api_hours_grid.php?iid=4246&  format=xml&weeks=1&systemTime=0";
  XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
  xdoc = XDocument.Load(URLString);


  var location = (from p in xdoc.Descendants("location")
                  from s in p.Descendants("week").Elements()
                  select new
                  {                  
                      CampusName = (string)p.Element("name"),
                      WeekD = (string)s.Element("date")
                  }).ToList();


                  foreach (var item in location)

                  {
                     foreach (var item in location)
                     {
                     <p>@item.WeekD</p>
                     }

                    <h2>@item.CampusName</h2>

                  }
}

</div>
```

Obviously the nested foreach loop is causing an error though. What I am trying to achieve is something like the following

```
<h2>Campus Name</h2>
<p>date</p>
<p>date</p>

<h2>Campus Name</h2>
<p>date</p>
<p>date</p>
```

and so on, can someone provide some advice on how I can get this result.

Comment: Why you defined two nested `foreach (var item in location)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Psuedo code)

```
string currentLocation = "";

foreach (var item in location)
{
   if(@item.CampusName != currentLocation)
   {
      <h2>@item.CampusName</h2>
      currentLocation = @item.CampusName;
   }
   <p>@item.WeekD</p>
}
```

Comment: Change `@item.CampusName = currentLocation;` to `currentLocation = @item.CampusName;` (you actually want to update `currentLocation` not `item.CampusName`)

Comment: brilliant! thanks so much PhillipH and Rafalon this got it but I had to use   <h2>@item.CampusName</h2>
              currentLocation = @item.CampusName;

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `GroupBy` your `CampusName` and then project your result to `ToDictionary` like

```
@using System;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Linq;
@using System.Xml.Linq;

<div>
    @{
        String URLString = "https://api3.libcal.com/api_hours_grid.php?iid=4246&  format=xml&weeks=1&systemTime=0";
        XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
        xdoc = XDocument.Load(URLString);


        var location = (from p in xdoc.Descendants("location")
                        from s in p.Descendants("week").Elements()
                        select new
                        {
                            CampusName = (string)p.Element("name"),
                            WeekD = (string)s.Element("date")
                        }).ToList();


        var result = location.GroupBy(x => x.CampusName)
               .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Select(x => x.WeekD));


        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            <h2>@item.Key</h2>
            foreach (var innerItem in item.Value)
            {
                <p>@innerItem</p>
            }
        }
    }

</div>
```

**Output:**  Output contains 6 row of location name but here I'm showing only 2 for simplicity

[image]

Comment: @IcantCode, view the answer might be it help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I made the code for you. Try it!

```
    string URLString = "https://api3.libcal.com/api_hours_grid.php?iid=4246&%20format=xml&weeks=1&systemTime=0";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(URLString );

    foreach (var element in xdoc.Descendants("location"))
    {
        var temp = element.Descendants("name");
        string name = "";
        if (temp.Count() != 0)
            name = temp.ToList()[0].Value;
        <h2>@name</h2>
        foreach (var d in element.Descendants("date"))
        {
            var date = d.Value;
            <p>date</p>
        }
    }
```